# How can \ifx\\\\ be false?

Tags: conditionals, debugging, primitives

It appears that I have a case where `\ifx\\#2\\` is false, even though `#2` is empty.

Here is the relevant excerpt from the log file, with `\tracingcommands` and `\tracingmacros` turned on:

```
\lastpageref ->\lastpagereftxt 

\lastpagereftxt #1->\pagesLTS@@pageref #1*\END 
#1<-pagesLTS.arabic

\pagesLTS@@pageref #1*#2\END ->\ifx \\#2\\\pagesLTS@@@pageref {#1}\else \expand
after \pagesLTS@@@pagerefstar \fi 
#1<-pagesLTS.arabic
#2<-
{restricted horizontal mode: \ifx}
{false}
```

As a result, `\pagaesLTS@@@pagerefstar` is called, and mayhem results. Not least because this happens in the output routine, while typesetting a complicated page header, and the next token happens to be `\cr`. But that is all beside the point, which is that this can't happen! And yet it does.

My question: How to debug something like this? Assuming it is not a bug in the TeX engine itself, there must be some natural explanation for it. I have verified (using `\show`) that `\ifx` really means `\ifx` at this point, and I assure you that there is no `\unless` lurking in the code either. And as far as I know, that exhausts the range of possible explanations. Can you come up with more possibilities I can look for?

**Edit:** I managed to chop the problem files down to size. Here is my input file:

```
\errorcontextlines=99
\documentclass{blargh}
\begin{document}
(Dummy text to ensure we get a page.)
\end{document}
```

And my class file, chopped down from over 300 lines to the bare essentials for this problem, and named `blarhg.cls`:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\LoadClass{report}
\RequirePackage[pagecontinue=false]{pageslts}

\AtBeginDocument{\thispagestyle{Eks}}

\def\PageText#1#2{Page #1 of #2}
\newtoks\firstpageupperright
\firstpageupperright{\PageText{\thepage}{\lastpageref{pagesLTS.arabic}}}

% Taken from pageslts.sty, so I could add \showtokens
\def\pagesLTS@@pageref#1*#2\END{%
  \ifx\\#2\\% no star
    \pagesLTS@@@pageref{#1}%
  \else% star
    \showtokens{"#2"}%
    \expandafter\pagesLTS@@@pagerefstar%
  \fi%
}

\def\ps@Eks{\let\@mkboth\@gobbletwo
     \def\@oddhead{\hfill \vtop to 0pt{\let\\\cr
                            \halign{\strut\hfil####\cr
                                    \relax\tracingall
                                    \the\firstpageupperright\cr
                                    \llap{}\cr}\vss}}
     \def\@oddfoot{}\let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot
     \let\@evenhead\@oddhead}
```

Comment: Could you give us a fuller example? Also, could you try `\showtokens{"#2"}` to see if there is a space or similar as part of `#2`.

Comment: space would be my guess (there is not one in the log as shown but it may have been trimmed while formatting)

Comment: Is this in a tabular or other alignment construct? I guess it is since you mention `\cr` probably the `\ifx` is expanding durong the pre-scan looking for `\omit` and the first ``\\`` expands then, and then the second ``\\`` isn't seen until after the cell template is inserted

Comment: @JosephWright I am working on chopping it down to a postable size. `\showtokens` shows that #2 is indeed empty.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It is, but inserting `\relax` in front to stop that didn't help. Besides, wouldn't the expansion of the double backslash [how do I type that so it shows correctly in a comment?] show up in the log?

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen Can you use e-TeX? The 'more robust' `\if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax` I think should work (need to see a full example).

Comment: Perhaps or perhaps not if the initial definition of `\\ ` was unexpandable (or was `\cr ` which changes things again) and I didn't get quite the same expansion as you got, but gut instinct suggested halign, then I saw you'd mentioned cr and I would  bet that is the case here.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I think you are onto something, but I still don't understand why. I have added a complete example to my question.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen as I said ... `(or was \cr which changes things again) `  :-)

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen You want to use two backticks on each side of ``\\`` :-)

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen Test for emptyness of `#2` with `\if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax` unless you *must* ensure compatibility with really old TeX distributions.

Comment: @egreg Sure, but I am not the author of `pageslts.sty`. I'll remember that one for my own code, though. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen Why don't you patch the code? The test I propose works exactly as ``\ifx\\#2\\`` would when it doesn't fail. And the proposed test won't fail in your case.

Comment: @egreg I can supply a redefinition of the offending macro in my own class file, but then a new version of `pageslts` could break it. Patching `pageslts.sty` itself is no solution, since my code is a class file distributed to a small, but significant, number of people. So I'm settling for David's solution. I might send the suggestion to the author of `pageslts`, however.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Update, in your MWE at the end of the class file change

```
\let\\\cr
```

to

```
\def\\{\cr}
```

If `\\` is `\cr` then `\ifx\\\\` is *interesting* :-)

---

The following plain TeX shows `\ifx\\\\` expanding  to false

```
{\tracingall
\def\\{\hfill\break}
\def\tablecr{{\global\let\\\relax}}
\halign{%
\expandafter
#\cr
\noexpand\ifx\\\\ A \else B \fi
C\cr
}
}

\bye
```

---

```
{\ifx: (level 1) entered on line 7}
{false}
{\else: \ifx (level 1) entered on line 7}
{the letter B}
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it. I get the mechanism in your plain TeX example, but I still don't quite understand what happened in my case. It must be related to the exact details of how and when TeX looks for `\cr` tokens inside a `\halign`? I had thought it would be too deeply buried in nested macros to make trouble, but I was wrong, evidently.

Comment: It sees the `\\ ` and ends the cell and tests something inside the cell template. If it is `\def` then it tests the `\\ ` token as intended

Comment: When I have more time to burn, I need to go back to the TeXbook and understand better how the body of `\halign` is parsed. (It's the details of when and why it “sees the ``\\``” that bother me; I understand that this is what happens.) But thanks again.